# TFS Automated Build error due to running lower node version than supported

Tags: node.js, angular, tfs

This is my first time trying to build something using an automated build on TFS.

I have an angular frontend project I am trying to get to build on TFS via an automated build process and get the following error when I run "npm run ng build --prod" in the command prompt in TFS.

*"You are running version v8.9.4 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater."*

I have searched on google and SO but have not found anything that is close enough to really help with this. How do I upgrade the version of Node that TFS is using? My local version is 12.7.

Comment: Its not the node version of the TFS but the node version installed on your build agent (agent pool). Check the node version on the agent who was assigned the build task. It should (hopefully) be printed within the pipeline terminals.

Comment: @mamichels I can't find the agent build version anywhere...I see the agent used in the Agent Queue but it doesn't  give me any information other than the name of the agent

Comment: The name of the agent probably is the machines name. Log onto it and check the version of node (`$node -v`).